# Filtering an array while slicing another array in the filter callback function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter an array A while slicing an array B using the index in the callback function filter.

```
const endResult = answers[user].filter((ans, index) => {

    if (ans !== '') {
        return true
    } else {
        console.log(index)
        outsideArray.splice(index, 1)
        return false
    }
})
```

It seems I can't use the index inside the filter callback function to splice another array. Is there a way to do this? I tried various things like map() without much success.

```
outsideArray: Array [ 1, 2, 4, 5 ]

answer[users]: Array [ "fff", "", "", "fffffff", "", "" ]
```

In the end, I get:

```
outsideArray: Array [ 1, 4 ]

answer[users]: Array [ "fff", "fffffff" ]
```

I should get:

```
outsideArray: Array [ ]

answer[users]: Array [ "fff", "fffffff" ]
```

Comment: it should work that way. please add some data to test.

Comment: What is the value of 'answers[user]' and 'outsideArray'?

Comment: add in your input data and expected output so that we know what you are trying to do

Comment: what do you expect your `outsideArray` to look after the operation has finished ??

Comment: thanks, done, check the updated question.

Comment: why should `outsideArray` be empty, if only three splices takes place?

Comment: you want to remove an element from `outsideArray` each time you get an empty string ? If so , is the element removed in ascending or descending order ?

Comment: It's removed in ascending order. Output of log is: 1 2 4 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually want to `splice` the exactly corresponding indices in your `outsideArray`; you want to remove *values* that match certain indices in `answer[users]`. Try this:

```
outsideArray.splice(outsideArray.indexOf(index), 1)
```

For example, in the second iteration of the filter call, we have the following:

- `index` is `1`
- `outsideArray` is `[ 1, 2, 4, 5 ]`

Now, if you splice `outsideArray` at index `1`, you'll get `[ 1, 4, 5 ]`. This is not that you want. You want to splice `outsideArray` at the index whose *value* is `1`. That's where `indexOf` comes in:

- `outsideArray.indexOf(index)` returns the first index in `outsideArray` where the value is equal to `1`. This is at index `0`.

If we splice `outsideArray` at index `0`, we get what we want: `[ 2, 4, 5 ]`.

Depending on your use case, there are definitely more efficient ways to design this. Currently, you're searching the entirety of `outsideArray` in every iteration of the `filter` call.

Comment: Ok my bad, I was deleting the elements found in the index instead of the values themselves!

Comment: Right. Although, as noted in my edit. there are probably more efficient ways to go about this depending on your use case.

Comment: `outsideArray.findIndex(val => val === index)` unnecessarily creates a predicate to test simple equality. It's preferable to use `indexOf` when testing simple equality.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to delete your array element in increasing order of index, you have to remove the first element each time you get an empty string.

```
const endResult = answers[user].filter((ans, index) => {
  if (ans !== '') {
      return true
  } else {
      outsideArray.splice(0, 1) // or outsideArray.shift()
      return false
  }
})
```

If in case you want your indexes to control what to delete from the array you would have to check for your callback's index and array's index match

```
const endResult = answers[user].filter((ans, index) => {
  const outsideArrayIndex = outsideArray.indexOf(index);
  if (outsideArrayIndex > -1) {
    outsideArray.splice(outsideArrayIndex,1);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the index directly to remove elements from the outside array, you are referring to the index in the outside array, not the value of each element, which is what it seems you are wanting.

```
outsideArray: Array [ 1, 2, 4, 5 ]
        (Indices are: 0  1  2  3)
```

So when you remove at index `1`, you remove the item with value `2`. The array is now:

```
outsideArray: Array [ 1, 4, 5 ]
        (Indices are: 0  1  2)
```

When you remove at index `2`, you remove the item with value `5`. The new array is:

```
outsideArray: Array [ 1, 4 ]
        (Indices are: 0  1)
```

Now you remove at indices `4` and `5`, but those items don't exists so it doesn't do anything.

What you seem to actually want is to remove the items by value. You can do this by searching the array for the item that matches the value of the index, like so:

```
outsideArray.splice(outsideArray.indexOf(index), 1)
```